# AND in Python's slicing with modulus

Tags: python

How can you fix the code?

I am trying to have `i % 3 == 1` and `i != 16` unsuccessfully by

```
data = "8|9|8|9|8|9|8|9|9|8|9|8|9|8|9|8"
arra = map(int,data.split("|"))

arra = sum(arra[1::3 and != 16]) for i in range(0, len(arra), 16)]        
                       |
                       |---// Problem here
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
arra = sum(a for i,a in enumerate(arra) if i %3==1 and i != 16)
```

For this kind of complex work, slice notation wont really do.  But why do you assign back to arra?  You wipe out your original list of values.

Answer (score 0):

Slices don't work like that.

[Paul McGuire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690203/and-in-pythons-slicing-with-modulus/1690245#1690245) has the correct code:

```
arra = sum(x for i, x in enumerate(arra) if i % 3 == 1 and i != 16)
```

It's also not clear from your code what the point of the `for i in range(0, len(arra), 16)]` is supposed to be.   What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The OP does not want to skip *values* == 16, but the *index* == 16.

Comment: @Paul McGuire: Ah yes.  My mistake.  I've corrected my answer.